# Valgrind error but no leak

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, free

My understanding is that for every malloc we should free before we exit.  Based on valgrind report, I do not have a leak.  That said, valgrind is reporting that this code has an error: `Address 0x402613c is 4 bytes inside a block of size 8 free'd`

For brevity, below is just snips of portions of linked list code that shows the node type and sections of code where I malloc or free the node.

```
typedef struct node
{
    int n;
    struct node* next;
}
node;

// global variable for the head of the list
node* head = NULL;

int main(void)
{
    // user menu
    while (true)
    {
        printf("Please choose an option (0, 1, 2): ");
        int option = GetInt();

        switch (option)
        {
            // quit
            case 0:
                free_nodes(head);
                printf("Goodbye!\n");
                return 0;

// snipped: code that calls insert and print functions

bool insert_node(int value)
{
    // create new node
    node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if (new_node == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // snipped: some code that adds nodes to linked list
 }   

/**
 * Frees all of the nodes in a list upon exiting the program.
 */
void free_nodes(node* list)
{       
    // initialize pointer
    node* curr_node = head;

    // initialize variable for end of list
    bool is_end = false;

    // free nodes
    while (!is_end)
    {
        // if an empty list, free node and exit
        if (curr_node->next == NULL)
        {
            free(curr_node);
            is_end = true;
        }
        // else free node list until end of list if found 
        else
        {
            free(curr_node);
            curr_node = curr_node->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `free(curr_node); curr_node = curr_node->next;` : You should not use a pointer that has been released already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you're using a pointer to freed memory after you freed it:

```
void *m = malloc(8);
char *s = m + 4;
free(m);
*s = 29;    // This would generate that warning.
int c = *s; // This would also generate that warning.
```

And, actually looking at your code, it is almost as blatant as the example above (as [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) points out in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275939/valgrind-error-but-no-leak/24275993#comment37507161_24275939)):

```
free(curr_node);
curr_node = curr_node->next;
```

Fix:

```
node *next = curr_node->next;
free(curr_node);
curr_node = next;
```

Comment: Many thanks.  After I saw @bluepixy and your note, I figured I needed a second pointer to track next but ran into issues when I though I also needed to `free(next)` before exiting.